# Get the distribution of $X|Y=y$ given this joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the joint probability density function

$f(x,y) = \lambda^2 \exp(-\lambda y)$ with $0 < x < y.$

How do I get the distribution of $X|Y=y$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given: $f_{X.Y}(x,y) = \lambda^2 (e^{-\lambda y}) \;\Bbb I_{(0<x<y)}$

Evaluate: $f_Y(y) = \int\limits_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y) \operatorname d x$

> $$ = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y} \int\limits_0^y\operatorname d x\;\Bbb I_{0<y} \\ = y\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y} \;\Bbb I_{0<y}$$

Then: $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

> $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) =\tfrac 1 y \;\Bbb I_{0<x<y}$$

Now, what distribution does that look like to you?

---

Perhaps the $y$ argument might throw you.   It's used an arbitrary constant, in this case.   Alpha-replace it with $c$ and consider $\;f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid c)\;$.   Does that look more familiar?

> $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid c)=\begin{cases} \tfrac 1 c & : x\in (0; c) \\ 0 & : x\notin (0; c)\end{cases}$$

---

> The continuous random variable, $\,X\,$, is distributed *uniformly* over the support of $\,(0; c)\,$ when under the condition that $\,Y=c\,$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awesome and really simple explanation! Just one thing: I don't really know if it's a known distribution, is it?

Comment: @DanielGrosso It is.  It should be quite familiar.  It's *one of* the first... if not **the** first ... distributions you should have met.  Perhaps the $y$ argument is throwing you, hm?  Replace it with $c$ and consider $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid c)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,Y)$ be the pair of random variables with the stated pdf:
$$
    f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = \begin{cases} \lambda^2 \exp\left(- \lambda y\right) & 0 < x < y \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
Consider a change of variables $Y = V$ and $X = U V$:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
    f_{U,V} \left(u,v\right) &=& f_{X,Y}\left(u v, v\right) \left| \begin{array}{cc} \partial x(u,v)/\partial u & \partial x(u,v)/\partial v \cr \partial y(u,v)/\partial u & \partial y(u,v)/\partial v \end{array} \right| = \begin{cases} v \lambda^2 \exp\left(- \lambda v\right) & v > 0,  \, 0<u<1 \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\
 &=& \begin{cases} v \lambda^2 \exp\left(- \lambda v\right) & v > 0 \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \cdot \begin{cases} 1 & 0 < u < 1 \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} = f_{V}\left(v\right) \cdot f_U\left(u\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
that is $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Now $\left(X \mid Y = y\right) \stackrel{d}{=} \left( V U \mid V = y\right) = \left( y U \mid V = y\right) =y \cdot U$.

Hence
$$
   f_{X\mid Y} \left(x \mid y\right) = \frac{1}{y}f_U\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{y} & 0 < x < y \cr 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$